# Why does Frankie Pentangeli immediately change his story when he sees his brother?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather-2

In *The Godfather 2* Frankie Pentangeli is before a committee ready give evidence against Michael Corleone. His brother enters the room and Frankie to immediately changes his story.

Was it just out of guilt or was there another less obvious reason?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's another less obvious reason that was left out of the final cut of the film.

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Pentangeli)

> The finished film leaves unclear exactly what about his brother's
>   presence motivated Frank to change his story. The final film only
>   states that Vincenzo is himself a Mafia chieftain in Sicily. An
>   early draft of the film explains that Vincenzo, shocked that Frankie
>   is about to break his blood oath and betray the Corleones to
>   government authorities, attends the hearing to remind Frankie that he
>   must not break the Mafia's code of silence, Omertà. His brother's
>   presence, as well as the stare they exchanged, serves as a threat that
>   if Frankie follows through with his planned testimony, retribution
>   will be taken against his children, who are living in Sicily under
>   Vincenzo's guardianship.

Comment: +1 Wow, never knew that. I always interpreted this along the lines of his brother sitting with *Michael*'s men as a sign to *Frankie* that they will punish his brother if *Frankie* talks. In fact his brother didn't come across like a Mafioso in any way (and I must have missed where they stated it).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - When Tom goes to visit Frankie in custody and they go through the story about how Romans would commit suicide in order to protect their families and make sure they were taken care of, Frankie mentions his brother was so powerful that he could have come to America and had his own crime family.

Answer (score 0):

I would assertively say that the capture of Pentangeli's brother by Michael may very well serve as a sign that Hyman Roth is on the dead list. That is to say, Hyman has lost all his power but Pentangeli, whose brother has been deprived of Hyman's protection (or surveillance) and exposed to the killing muscle of Michael. Your brother is on your enemy's hand and so are all your other odds. The only way out is to get what your enemy wants.

Answer (score -1):

This is correct. At one point in his testimony, Frank Pentangeli says "I have a family of my own" (or something very close to that), meaning, they'd be in danger if he testified against the Corleones.

Answer (score -2):

> I have a family of my own, Senator.

I took this statement as a way of letting the committee know that if he testifies his entire family will all die quite gruesomely. The look from his brother also meant that Frankie’s entire life would stand for nothing.